# ASP MVC 4 client side validation not working in IE (works in Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've seen similar issues posted on Stack Overflow but nothing specific to this case. For whatever reason, the ASP.Net MVC 4 client side validation works fine in Chrome, but will not fire in IE9.

**Web.config**

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

**View**

Anything can be entered into these two fields and they'll be posted back to the server. For example `55/55/5555` will trigger an error in Chrome and prevent the form from posting, however in IE the form will send the data back to the server and crash the site...

Below is the jquery input mask applied to each field and the Razor syntax.

```
$('#EffectiveDate').mask('99/99/9999');
$('#Birthdate').mask("99/99/9999");

<div class="M-editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EffectiveDate, new {@class="required"})
</div>
<div class="M-editor-field">          
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EffectiveDate, new { maxlength = 10 })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EffectiveDate)
</div>
<div class="M-editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Birthdate, new {@class="required"})
</div>
<div class="M-editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Birthdate)
    <br />
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Birthdate)
</div>
```

**Layout.cshtml**

Here is the rendered script section

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/typeahead.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery.numeric.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.fancybox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.fancybox.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Model**

```
    [DisplayName("Effective Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? EffectiveDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Date of Birth")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Move [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/#installing) ahead of all scripts in the `<head>` section.

Comment: Still no luck, same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at working sample https://dotnetfiddle.net/fEER2v

The problem is in the date localization and jQuery validation plugin. The easiest way to fix is to override the `date` validator. This is sample code of how to it, that uses [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) javascript library:

```
  $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
       return value === "" || moment(value, "MM/DD/YYYY", true).isValid();
  };
```

It also available via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moment.js/)

Of course you will need some optimization, like getting the date format from element attributes.